# JGroups cluster of members on the same host is using only one address

Tags: java, jgroups

I want do develop some distributed application using JGroups. But unfortunately I am not able to get more then one member on a cluster. They always join to the same address:

```
    this.channel = new JChannel("udp.xml");
    channel.connect("test-cluster");
    this.rpcDispatcher = new RpcDispatcher(channel, null, null, this);
    this.myAddress = channel.getAddress();

    System.out.println("joined cluster: " + channel.getView().size() + ", " + channel.getView());
```

When I start two (or more) debugging sessions I will always end up with a cluster of size 1.

```
joined cluster: 1, [Jimbo-3806|0] [Jimbo-3806]
```

And as a result of that you can not send direct messages from one jvm to another (since you need to pass the Address which is the same).

I am using the default udp.xml bundled with JGroups.

Comment: I guess you need to call `connect(clusterName)` in the channel to join the cluster.

Comment: @Ruben yes you are right, actually I am doing that. I have just copied two classes together for the question here and missed that part to copy (originally I pass the connected channel to the constructor). I have edited my question for that.

Comment: I suggest you go through this page in order to find out if the problem is on your code or in your machine: http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html#TestingTheSetup

Comment: Hmmm the draw demo is working properly

Comment: In fact I had to use System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true"); in front of new JChannel(). For some weird reason the property in the run configuration of intellij was not used and the jvm stuck to IPv6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is facing this problem. Make sure the [draw demo](http://jgroups.org/manual/index.html#TestingTheSetup) is working properly and your JVM is using IPv4 (which is important). In my case the JVM stuck to IPv6 and I had to force the JVM to use IPv4 like so:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
Channel channel = new JChannel("udp.xml");
channel.connect("test-cluster");
```